# uniq_ptr direct assignment

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have a function like this:

```
unique_ptr<int> foo() {
    return unique_ptr<int>(new int[4])
}
```

When calling this foo(), what I do is:

```
unique_ptr<int> t = foo()
```

I am wondering is there any problem in this piece of code? Should I use something
like std::move instead of assigning directly? Can I return the unique ptr by reference, like:

```
unique_ptr<int>& foo() {
    return unique_ptr<int>(new int[4])
}
```

Comment: What does the `[...]` in `unique_ptr<int>(new int[...])` represent?  You're not allocating an array there are you?  Because if you are, you have undefined behavior when that `unique_ptr` is destroyed.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, Good point. I assumed it was allocating a single element.

Comment: why? unique_ptr will destroy the array, right?

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld, It defaults to `delete ptr;`. You need to use an empty array type argument to make it use `delete[] ptr;`, and using the wrong one is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will automatically use the move constructor if no RVO takes place, so it's all good. You definitely do not want to return a reference, as it would dangle. Do note that no assignment is being done here anyway, though. And as Benjamin points out, now that you've filled in the ellipsis, you need to use `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` to allocate that sort of memory.